# How to target collection, document id, sub collection in Firebase?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I'm  working with the Firestore database, I have a collection, doc id, sub collection. I want to get data using onSnapshot, and I want to use orderby. So how I can target all these?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in the example provided in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#listen_to_multiple_documents_in_a_collection) (see below) you can pass a [`Query`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.query.md#query_class) as the first argument of the [`onSnapshot()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_#onsnapshot) method. (Note that the `CollectionReference` class extends the `Query` class, so you can also pass a `CollectionReference` to `onSnapshot()`).

**Example from the Firestore documentation:**

```
import { collection, query, where, onSnapshot } from "firebase/firestore";

const q = query(collection(db, "cities"), where("state", "==", "CA")); // <= Query using where

const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(q, (querySnapshot) => {
  const cities = [];
  querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      cities.push(doc.data().name);
  });
  console.log("Current cities in CA: ", cities.join(", "));
});
```

So you should declare a `Query` using the `orderBy()` method, as also shown in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data#order_and_limit_data) (see below) and pass this query to the `onSnapshot()` method.

**Example from the Firestore documentation:**

```
import { query, orderBy, limit } from "firebase/firestore";  

const q = query(citiesRef, orderBy("name"), limit(3));
```

---

Since you don't give any detail on which exact subcollection you want to query (a specific `messages` subcollection? All the `messages` ones?) and on which field you want to order it, it's difficult to help you in more detail.

Comment: Hello @user20492045, did you have the time to look at the proposed solution?